# how to resolve Build error while compiling motioneyeos

Tags: python, github

I am trying to compile the motioneyeos from github in ubuntu, I am getting the following error:

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 SSL is required 2018-02-13
>   09:25:27 ERROR 403: SSL is required.

I tried to fix this with

```
pip install xxxx -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

but inturn got an error

> Collecting xxxx   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement xxxx (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   xxxx

For which I am unable to fix the error.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be fixed, as described in [ccrisan/motioneyeos issue 1210](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/issues/1210)
.

Check if [ccrisan/thingos commit c508ee6](https://github.com/ccrisan/thingos/commit/c508ee6b3f8dc4a822556a66412b770b7167abfd) was merged into motioneyeos.

As commented in [ccrisan/motioneyeos/issue 1211](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/issues/1211#issuecomment-341344096):

> the pycurl problem has been reported in #1210.
>   I'll probably have to update the buildroot package.
>
> Until then, I recommend manually downloading `pycurl-7.19.5.1.tar.gz` and placing it in the `.download` folder.